# How to send a request from angular front end to laravel API?

Tags: php, angularjs, api, laravel-5

I'm building a RESTful API with Laravel 5.2 and I have an AngularJS 1.5 front end. I am successfully writing services to get information but I am having troubble putting or posting anything to the database when I pass it to the API. I've tried doing some searching and but I just don't understand how to actually save data I would send the API. Here is my attempt so far:

-Service from the Factory-

```
addReceipt: function(request) { 
            return $http.post(api_url + "/rewards/receipts/add", request).then(function(results) {
              console.log(results);
              return results.data;
            });
        }
```

-From the Controller

```
$scope.submitReceipt = function() {
                rewardsFactory.addReceipt($scope.model).then(function() {
                    console.log($scope.model);
                    toaster.pop({ type: 'success', title: 'Claim Submitted!', body: "Thanks! We'll take a look at your claim shortly.", showCloseButton: true });
                });
            };
```

-From Laravel API routes

```
Route::post('rewards/receipts/add', 'Rewards\RewardsController@addReceipt');
```

-From Laravel Controller

```
public function addReceipt(Request $request)
    {
        //Add the Receipt
        DB::table('receipts')->insert(
            ['transaction_id' => $request->input('transactionID'), 
             'client_id' => $request->input('client_id'), 
             'location_id' => $request->input('location_id') ]
        );
    }
```

My Current Cors setup seems to be working out well enough for at least some traffic so I don't think that is the problem but I'm just still not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Do you know where the breakdown is? When in doubt, log, log, log.

Comment: Does your frontend have the Laravel security token? That borked my last Laravel API for quite a while.

Comment: \Log::info($request) in the controller to see if your request data gets to the controller. Remember to clear your logs before

Comment: note that `$http` does not send form encoded data by default, it sends `application/json` in request body so `$request->input` is probably empty. See what `json_decode($request->getContent())` does for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `$http` does not send form encoded data by default, it sends `application/json` in request body.

I don't do any work with laravel but if you check `$_POST` you will see it is empty so  `$request->input` is probably empty also.

In  php you can access the response body using :

```
json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')[,true/*optional to convert to array*/])
```

I believe that `json_decode($request->getContent())` will do the same in laravel

The alternative is to use the following `$http` set up taken from the docs to send form encoded data

```
.controller(function($http, $httpParamSerializerJQLike) {
  //...

  $http({
    url: myUrl,
    method: 'POST',
    data: $httpParamSerializerJQLike(myData),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
  });

});
```

You can also set `$http.defaults` in a run block so all post or put are sent as `x-www-form-urlencoded` and not have to add the config to each use